# Applying Backslash To A Variable (Not String.raw)

Tags: javascript, unicode, escaping

I want to get newline character `\n` from a variable (`char`) which contains `'n'`

I tried this:

```js
`\\${char}`; // Not working, its 2 character not a newline character
'\' + char;  // Obviously this will not work
```

Did something, for example, `String.applyBackslash()` exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a method like that, no. :-) There are two ways to do it:

1. A lookup table (object or `Map`) mapping `n` to `\n`, etc. (There aren't that many escape sequences.)
2. `eval`, which is probably overkill but is okay **if and only if** you control the input sufficiently that you know it won't be used for malicious code injection.

Example of #1:

```js
const mappings = Object.assign(Object.create(null), {
    '"': '"',
    "'": "'",
    "\\": "\\",
    b: "\b",
    f: "\f",
    n: "\n",
    r: "\r",
    t: "\t",
});
const stringToTreatLiterally = "Testing \\n1\\n2\\n3";
console.log(JSON.stringify(
    stringToTreatLiterally.replace(
        /\\(["'\\bfnrt])/g,
        (m, c) => `${mappings[c] || c}`
    )
));
```

If you want to handle `\uNNNN` or `\u{NNNN}`, they aren't that much more complicated, but you have to capture the number and use either `String.fromCharCode` or `String.fromCodePoint` to create the ersult.

Comment: I think i prefer option one, thanks for the idea (now im waiting for another answer, maybe they still writing)

Comment: @Hanz - I prefer option 1 as well. :-)